# MVC 4 Bundling and referencing jquery in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Why do I still need to reference jquery in my view pages, when it is bundled and being loaded in the _layout.cshtml?

If I do not reference jquery.js file in my view page, my jquery will not work.

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*",
                        "~/Scripts/Bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-modalmanager.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Content/Site.css",
                        "~/Content/Bootstrap.min.css",
                        "~/Content/Bootstrap-responsive.css",
                        "~/Content/bootstrap-modal.css"
                        ));



        }
```

This does not work without referencing jquery in my view:

```
    @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btn1").click(function () {
                    alert("Text: " + $("#test").text());
                });
                $("#btn2").click(function () {
                    alert("HTML: " + $("#test").html());
                });
            });
        </script>


        <p id="test">This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>
        <button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
        <button id="btn2">Show HTML</button>
```

This works with added reference :

```
            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Index";
            }

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
            </script>


            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btn1").click(function () {
                        alert("Text: " + $("#test").text());
                    });
                    $("#btn2").click(function () {
                        alert("HTML: " + $("#test").html());
                    });
                });
            </script>


            <p id="test">This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>
            <button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
            <button id="btn2">Show HTML</button>
```

Comment: How is your layout look like? How do you use the scripts in your view? Do you put your scripts inside the script section?

Comment: My crystal ball isn't working this morning, We'll need to see some code: The bundling (in BundleConfig), how you are referencing the bundling and what you're trying to do with jQuery.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you're trying to use jQuery before defining it.  Read the generated source.

Comment: Are you referencing the correct bundle in the layout? Based on your bundle config I believe it should be  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Bootstrap")

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Bootstrap") is being rendered.  They are all in the Scripts folder

Comment: is the jquery library in ~/scripts have the version in the name (ex jquery-1.10.1.js ) or is it just named jquery.js? Also, when you view source on the page are you seeing the ~/scripts version of your jquery lib referenced?

Comment: yes, it has full jquery.1.7.2.js

Comment: There is your problem. The bundling config is looking for a dash in the file name. See "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"

Comment: sorry it does have a dash, correct is jquery-1.7.2.js

Comment: Try to put your `<script>` inside the `scripts` section e.g: `@section Scripts { <script>
            $(document).ready(function () { ... } </script> }`

Comment: Have you tried using the Network tab in the browser's developer tools to make sure the URL that is getting emitted is correct?

Comment: I found out the problem...   my jquery script was being loaded after the body tag.  Visual Studio empty MVC project puts the jquery bundling after the body in _layout.  This is wrong! I moved it up to where it should be up at the top and now it works.